# Passing an ID to a child component in angular

Tags: angular, data-binding, components

I have three components

A list component that does a request to receive an object, then a card component that is iterated for each object passed onto an array from the List component, lastly, I have a Detail component which im trying to pass an ID which is present in the object that is passed from the List component to the Card component.

I dont know how to pass this id.

List Component

```
this.webService.getObjects().subscribe((res : any) =>  {
      console.log(res) 
      this.cards = res.results  <-- An Array
      console.log(res.results)
      
    })
```

List Template:

```
<app-card class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let card of cards"
    [card]={card}></app-card> <-- object passed to Card Component
```

Card Component:

```
@Input() 
  game : any
```

Card Template:

```
 <a href="javascript: void" [routerLink]="['',card.card.name]" class="btn btn-primary align-items-center">Detail</a>
```

How do I pass an ID that inside an object that is passed from the List Component into the Card Component?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing id inside card input parameter, so you can access to that card data inside html using (?) to avoid to try to access to invalid reference.

```
 <a href="javascript: void" [routerLink]="['',card?.id]"   class="btn btn-primary align-items-center">Detail</a>
```